# Find reflex angle with 3 points and their plane normal

Tags: geometry, angle

I have 3 points in 3D and I want to calculate $ABC$ angle, which could be reflex angle. I also know the normal of the plane they are in. Is there a way to calculate the angle?

EDIT:

Take a look at this [picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WweDu.png). The two vectors create two angles one would be $a$ and the other $360 - a$. Now I also know the direction of normal between the two vectors. With that information how can I determine if they construct angle $a$ or $360-a$.

Comment: You will have to be clearer about what you want.

Comment: @Paul updated my question with more clarification.

Comment: Sorry, still no clearer. I cannot see how your clarification relates to your original question.. In your clarification, what do you mean by "the direction of normal between the two vectors"? Also, any angle is relative to a given direction - it could, for example, be the angle measured from one vector anticlockwise to the other. Where are you measuring angle from?

Comment: @Paul The two vectors can have two normals (In different direction of the plane they are in). Now I know which one is the "correct" one. In other words I know the orientation. That means the vectors are not placed arbitrarily, but lie within a plane with a known normal vector n.

Comment: Is this normal vector irrelevant then? You just want the angle between 2 vectors in a plane?

Comment: @Paul No it is not. As I said it could be the reflex angle. The normal vector here should enable us to determine if it is reflex angle or not.

Comment: Possibly, if u and v are your two vectors then calculate $u\times v$. If it is a positive multiple of n, your normal vector, then the angle measured from u to v is less than $180^o$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found a solution for this case in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14066933/direct-way-of-computing-clockwise-angle-between-2-vectors).

The part that is relevant for this question:

When your vectors are not placed arbitrarily, but lie within a plane with a known normal vector $n$. Then the axis of rotation will be in direction $n$ as well, and the orientation of $n$ will fix an orientation for that axis. In this case you can calculate the angle via:

$$dot = x_1x_2 + y_1y_2 + z_1z_2$$
$$det = x_1y_2z_n + x_2y_nz_1 + x_ny_1z_2 - z_1y_2*x_n - z_2y_nx_1 - z_ny_1*x_2$$
$$angle = arctan(det, dot)$$

One condition for this to work is that the normal vector n has unit length. If not, you'll have to normalize it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use scalar product
$$
\langle \mathbf{u},\mathbf{v}\rangle = \lVert \mathbf{u}\rVert \lVert \mathbf{v}\rVert \cos\alpha
$$
where $\alpha$ is the angle between $\mathbf{u}$ and $\mathbf{v}$.

Hence
$$
\alpha=\arccos \frac{\langle \mathbf{u},\mathbf{v}\rangle}{\lVert \mathbf{u}\rVert \lVert \mathbf{v}\rVert}
$$

In your case
\begin{align}
\mathbf{u}=A-B\\
\mathbf{v}=C-B
\end{align}

Notice that you'll get $\alpha\le180°$.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I was looking to determine if it is reflex angle (more than 180 degree) or not. This (hopefully) could be achieved with the knowing the normal of the plane they are embedded in.

Comment: What do you mean "determine *if* it is reflex angle". You always get two angles $\hat{ABC}\le 180°$ and $\check{ABC}\ge 180°$. With the procedure I told you, you can compute $\alpha=\hat{ABC}$, then you have $\check{ABC}=360°-\alpha$.

Comment: Not if you know the normal. You can decide which angle to choose.

Comment: How would you make such decision?

Comment: That is basically my question.

Comment: I mean, what distinguish one angle from the other beside their value? I think there's some information you're leaving out.